# What is happening to Martin Gardner's files?

Tags: ho.history-overview, recreational-mathematics, soft-question, tag-removed

Martin Gardner kept voluminous correspondence with amateur and professional mathematicians worldwide throughout his career.  His files are a treasure trove of information about all areas of recreational mathematics.  Does anybody here know whether any portion of those files will be made available to the public for research purposes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to a simple Google search, the papers were donated to Stanford.

http://www.oac.cdlib.org/data/13030/6s/kt6s20356s/files/kt6s20356s.pdf

Comment: I did, in fact, search Google for about fifteen minutes before posting, but clearly your skills are better than mine.  Thanks!

Comment: "martin gardner" papers

Comment: that was the Google search